# Como verificar eventos entre 2 datas no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

Sabendo que tenho uma tabela chamada `eventos`, e esta tabela possui as colunas `id`, `titulo`, `inicio` e `fim`. As colunas `inicio` e `fim` são do tipo *timestamp*, onde é gravado a data e a hora de início e término de um certo evento. Ao fazer um `select` nesta tabela, como faço para pegar os eventos de uma data específica que fique entre a data da coluna *inicio* e a coluna *fim*?

**Exemplo:** Supondo que eu tenha um registro nesta tabela com a coluna *inicio* tendo o valor `2014-02-01 13:00:00` e a coluna *fim* com o valor `2014-02-05 22:30:00`. É um intervalo de 4 dias, e suas respectivas horas. Como eu poderia pegar esse registro em um dia específico usando a seguinte SQL abaixo?

```
SELECT titulo
FROM eventos
WHERE inicio <= '2014-02-03'
AND fim >= '2014-02-03'
```

Um dos problemas, é que se meu registro está com a coluna inicio com valor `2014-02-01 13:00:00` e eu consultar por `WHERE inicio <= '2014-02-01'`, ou seja, mesma data do início, não é encontrado. Sabendo que tenho o operador `<=`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use o operador `BETWEEN` para facilitar e converta `DATETIME` para `DATE`.

Exemplo:

```sql
SELECT titulo
FROM eventos
WHERE '2014-02-01' BETWEEN date(inicio) AND date(fim)
```

Veja o exemplo no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4852/4).

A função [`date()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) do MysQL extrai somente a parte da data para ignorar a hora na comparação.

---

Se quiser fazer isso sem o `BETWEEN`:

```sql
SELECT titulo
FROM   eventos
WHERE  '2014-02-01' >= date(inicio)
  AND  '2014-02-01' <= date(fim)
```

Veja o [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4852/5).

Comment: Perfeito, era isso mesmo :)

Answer (score 2):

Se você for comparar com uma única data o inicio e o fim do intervalo então uma alternativa para a consulta é utilizar o `BETWEEN`, exemplo:

```
SELECT titulo
FROM eventos
WHERE '2014-02-03' BETWEEN DATE(inicio) AND DATE(fim)
```

Comment: Era isso aí Maicon, só faltou o date() no nome das colunas. Obrigado!

Comment: Eu que agradeço, desculpa por ter esquecido da função.

Answer (score 0):

Você esta tendo o mesmo problema que o meu, o `BETWEEN` em alguns bancos não traz o valor exato do mesmo dia, tente e `>= e <=` no banco é a mesma coisa que `BETWEEN`, coloca um dia a mais nessa sua busca por ex:

```
SELECT titulo
FROM eventos
WHERE inicio >= '2014-02-03'
AND fim <= '2014-02-04'
```

Answer (score -5):

Você errou na lógica eu imagino, o certo seria o contrário dos operadores:

```
SELECT titulo
FROM eventos
WHERE inicio >= '2014-02-03'
AND fim <= '2014-02-03'
```

Comment: Isto só selecionaria os registos cuja data inicio e data fim fossem ambas iguais a 2014-02-03