# Pesquisa por intervalo de Data em SQL

Tags: mysql

Possuo uma tabela com a estrutura abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso fazer uma consulta com um determinado intervalo, afim de gerar um relatório. Usei o comando Between... e com isso ele me retorna os seguintes valores

[image: Valores de Retorno]

Porem para a interface eu preciso apresentar da forma dd-mm-yyyy e não como o banco salva que é yyyy-mm-dd.

Ja usei o comando

```
select * from venda where data_venda = DATE_FORMAT('18-01-2016', '%d-%m-%Y')

SELECT * FROM venda WHERE STR_TO_DATE(data_venda, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2016/01/18','%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('2016/02/15','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Mas sempre retorna um valor nulo.

Será que alguém ai já fez isso e poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Tem uma confusão na pergunta. Uma coisa é o formato pra mostrar na tela, que é o que vem depois do SELECT e antes do FROM. Outra é o que você usa na pesquisa, no WHERE. Se quer exibir de maneira diferente, troque aquele asterisco pelo campo desejado com a formatação desejada, e deixe o WHERE trabalhar com o formato correto ( aaaa-mm-dd ). Como pesquisar entre duas datas já foi respondido aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4177/

Comment: Poderia descrever como ficaria por gentileza? O que preciso é que volte ja no formato correto pois estou preenchendo uma jTable com o resultado do select.

Comment: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT( data_venda, '%d-%m-%Y') AS datavenda FROM venda WHERE data_venda BETWEEN '2016-01-18' AND '2016-02-15'` Pra usar mais campos, pode colocar antes do DATE_FORMAT, ou depois do AS datavenda, separando com virgula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente isso:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( data_venda, '%d-%m-%Y') AS datavenda
  FROM venda
  WHERE data_venda BETWEEN '2016-01-18' AND '2016-02-15'
```

Para usar mais campos:

```
SELECT campo1, campo2, DATE_FORMAT( data_venda, '%d-%m-%Y') AS datavenda, campo3
   ...etc...
```

O `AS datavenda` é o nome que você quer usar como retorno para a pesquisa. De preferência, use um nome que não seja repetido como campo da tabela, para evitar confusão.

Pode até usar o asterisco, mas o campo virá sem formatar no asterisco, e  formatado ao final:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT( data_venda, '%d-%m-%Y') AS datavenda
  FROM venda
  WHERE data_venda BETWEEN '2016-01-18' AND '2016-02-15'
```

Mas não recomendo. É sempre bom especificar apenas os campos que vai usar.

Comment: Ajudou muito... Obrigado tenha um bom dia!!!

Answer (score 1):

Basta no seu select você especificar e formatar o output com o padrão desejado exemplo:

```
SELECT 
    id_venda,
    DATE_FORMAT(data_venda,'%d-%m-%Y'),
    valor_venda,
    id_cliente
FROM venda
```

O ponto negativo é que você precisará especificar os fields contudo desconheço outra forma de chegar ao seu resultado.

OBS: não coloquei sua clausula where porque não sabia qual das duas você pretende usar contudo elas não precisam ser modificadas.

Answer (score 1):

Está formatando a data erroneamente na condicão WHERE. Apenas remova a formatação.

Para receber a data formatada, faça isso no trecho do SELECT. Exemplo de correção:

```
select 
id_venda,
DATE_FORMAT(data_venda, '%d-%m-%Y') as data_venda,
valor_venda,
id_cliente
from venda where data_venda = '2016-01-18'
```

A mesma coisa na segunda query. Conserte seguindo a mesma lógica do exemplo acima.