# consultar registro entre duas datas no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta no MySql da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `data` >= '2017-03-01' AND `data` <='2017-03-05')
```

A questão é que mesmo tendo vários registros do dia 2017-03-05, a consulta só me retorna registros até o dia 2017-03-04. Eu preciso ter o retorno dos registros do dia 2017-03-05, sem ter que utilizar uma data acima.

Alguém tem uma solução pra me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta usar com between

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `data` between '2017-03-01' AND '2017-03-05'
```

Caso esteja usando DateTime, coloque a data inicial como 00:00:00 e data final como 23:59:59 para considerar os dois dias inteiros

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `data` between '2017-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-05 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Era isso. Valeu!

Comment: @BrunoOliveira se a resposta do colega Antonio ajudou e resolveu o problema pff dê como aceite: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta por baixo das setas cima/baixo à esquerda da resposta

Comment: Uma dúvida: é uma prática correta quando for DateTime fazer isso? Por que eu faço, mas acho estranhão... Será que não tem uma solução melhor pra contar o dia todo, tipo uma função?

Answer (score 0):

Esta consulta só verifica no intervalo até o dia 05/03/2017 às 00:00hrs. Tente colocar no último parâmetro a data completa, exemplo:

`SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE data >= '2017-03-01' AND data <='2017-03-05 23:59:00'`

Levando em consideração que o campo é do tipo `datetime` ou `timestamp`.

Sugiro otimizar melhor sua consulta retirando os operadores de igualdade.

`SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE data BETWEEN '2017-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-05 23:59:00'`

Comment: Valeu meu camarada! Resolvido.

Comment: Por nada. Disponha!

Comment: A comunidade já deu muito *downvote* por conta do uso de consultas entre datas assim. [Veja](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4177/como-verificar-eventos-entre-2-datas-no-mysql)